# Kotlin: setOnClickListener on Fragment Crashes app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin, android-tabbed-activity

I have a MainActivity with a button that calls on a **tabbedActivity** with **FragmentOneActivity** and **fragment_one.xml**. I have placed my button in the **fragment_one.xml** and perform a Toast on **FragmentOneActivity**. Here's my code:

```
class Anct3bActivity : Fragment() {
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    val v : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_anct3b, container, false)

    calculateNutCountButton.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(
            activity,"Success.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    return v
}
```

}

My application starts fine but when a click the button that calls on **tabbedActivity**, my application crashes. However, when I delete the **calculateButton.setOnClickListener** from **FragmentOneActivity** the **tabbedActivity** works fine.

I also tried placing the **calculateButton.setOnClickListener** on **tabbedActivity** but it still crashes.

Its my first time venturing into tabbed activities but I can't someone use a **setOnClickLIstener**.

Kindly walk me through this. Thanks!

Logcat:

**On FragmentOneActivity:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

**On tabbedActivity**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.demicode.ccdofieldkit/com.a.fr.meActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: What is your error in logcat?

Comment: Sounds like you are not using synthetic imports and you are not initializing `calculateButton` with `findViewById`

Comment: Call `setOnClickListener` in `onViewCreated` override method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your on click listener in onViewCreated, in onCreateView you are calling onClick listener before the view could set.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    calculateNutCountButton.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(
            activity,"Success.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```